# Java - Subtracting Value from database and executing multiple queries

Tags: java, database, subtraction

how could i subtract a value based on the input on the  text field directly to my database?
and how can i execute two queries at the same time i tried doing this but i had no luck

heres the code i am trying to execute

```
String sql1 = "select seat from passenger_details where seat = '"+seats+"'";

resultset = statement.executeQuery(sql1);
int count = 0;
while(resultset.next()) {
    count = count + 1;
}

if(cc.equals("")||add.equals("")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Complete the form");
} else {
    sql1 = "INSERT INTO passenger_details(fname,lname,gender,address,cc_no,bank_name,no_of_tickets,seat) VALUES('"+fnm+"','"+lnm+"','"+gnd+"','"+add+"','"+cc+"','"+bank+"','"+tckts+"','"+seats+"'),('"+fnm+"','"+lnm+"','"+gnd+"','"+add+"','"+cc+"','"+bank+"','"+tckts+"','"+seats2+"'),('"+fnm+"','"+lnm+"','"+gnd+"','"+add+"','"+cc+"','"+bank+"','"+tckts+"','"+seats3+"'),('"+fnm+"','"+lnm+"','"+gnd+"','"+add+"','"+cc+"','"+bank+"','"+tckts+"','"+seats4+"'),('"+fnm+"','"+lnm+"','"+gnd+"','"+add+"','"+cc+"','"+bank+"','"+tckts+"','"+seats5+"')";
    String sql2 = "Update flight_details set seats_avail= seats_avail-'"+tckts+" Where route_name = '"+dest+"'";

    statement.addBatch(sql1);
    statement.addBatch(sql2);
    statement.executeBatch();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sucess");
}
```

Comment: why do you want to execute two queries at once? a) not all drivers/databases support it, b) just execute two queries

Comment: a driver which doesnt support the driver-specific equivalent of executeBatch() isnt actually a real driver, im gonna go ahead and say "every driver supports it in its own implementation"

Comment: @Bohemian I need to insert something into one table of my database
and at the same time I need to update something on the another table
and nothing happens when i execute two queries